# metasploit-framework gem not found issue in ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, metasploit

I'm trying to install metasploit for ubuntu 14 ,but there is a big problem when installing required gems .Actually , metasploit-framework gem is not found even in rubygems.com . Is there any solution to fix this issue or can I find the required gem anywhere else in the internet  ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer from Metasploit.com comes with it's own set of gems and built in ruby, so I assume you are trying to go through the process of using the GIT version from https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework. If so, you might need to update as I don't recall there every being a "metasploit-framework" gem being required. If you can post more output from the console where you are trying to start Metasploit this may help.